# I want to install git in Ubuntu but I am getting error

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am getting error like below

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I got answer 
Before typing sudo apt-get install terminal

type the following on terminal

sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock

sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock

sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock

Answer (score 0):

If you already runs GUI Synaptic Package Manager, and try to run "sudo apt-get install" from Terminal console, this error will occur.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

---

Put in terminal...

```
chown root:root `which sudo`
```

then

```
chwon root:root /usr/bin/sudo
```

then

```
chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
```

then type

```
reboot
```

---

Source:

- https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/sudo-must-be-setuid-root-854117/

---

Hope this helps, enjoy!